# How to export four columns from a datatable which has 19 columns into an Excel file in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

There is a datatable which has 19 columns and almost 55 rows. I would like to create an Excel file which will contain only 4 of those columns ("Persons Name", "Mailing Address", "Country-State-Zip") and all the data from the original datatable.

Note: the column country, state and zip are separated in original datatable and the name of the columns are "Column12", "Column13", "Column14".

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have tried by myself but i can export all data (column) from original data-table where i would like to export only 4 column from original data-table. I saw that link but nothing did not match with my problem.

Comment: Think about how you can solve this.....  Your could i.e. create a copy of this data-table with only the four columns you need.  Then your situation matches (some of) the examples found by the link.

Answer (score 0):

I am using always this to  create excel file (of course i suppose you have installed interops Excel)

Sample to write to a new excel:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
//First we have to initialize the Excel application Object.
Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

//Before creating new Excel Workbook, you should check whether Excel is installed in your system.
if (excelApp == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
    return;
}

Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets.Add();

//fill 4 rows of col 1
excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "NameOfCol1";
excelWorksheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Value1";
excelWorksheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Value2";
excelWorksheet.Cells[4, 1] = "Value3";

excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(@"C:\abc.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);

excelWorkbook.Close();
excelApp.Quit();
```

Of course you adapt to your problem. So you could write your datatable easily in an excel file

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all to help me out. I got my answer. According to the suggestion first i combine 3 column into one Column original data table (City + State + Zip). Then i extract 3 columns from original data-table. My code is:

//Combine 3 Columns into original data-table (dt) and named it "City-State-Zip".

dt.Columns.Add("City-State-Zip", typeof(string), "Column12+','+Column13+','+Column14").ToString();

//Extract three columns from original data-table (dt) into dt2

dt2 = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "Board Member Name", "Current Address", "Permanent Mailing Address", "City-State-Zip");

And now i can create excel file using the data-table (dt).